# undefined method `articles_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x0000000000b450>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the controller named Articles

```
def new
    @article =Article.new
  end
  

  def show
    @article=Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @article=Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

This is the view

```
<h1>New Article</h1>

<%form_for(@article) do |form|%>
    <div>
        <%=form.label :title%><br>
        <%=form.text_field :title%>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%=form.label :body%><br>
        <%=form.text_field :body%>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%=form.submit%>
    </div>
<%end%>
```

This is the routes

```
get 'articles/new', to: 'articles#new'
  post 'articles/create', to: 'articles#create'
```

when I want to access the route http://localhost:3000/articles/new it gives error undefined method `articles_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x0000000000b450>

Answer (score 1):

The error is raised within `form_for`. When new `article` object is given, it has to guess the path the form will be submitted to. Following convention, it tries to execute `"#{object.model_name.plural}_path"`

Your routes has no names and do not generate helpers. You can give them names explicitly with:

```
get 'articles/new', to: 'articles#new', as: :new_article
post 'articles/create', to: 'articles#create', as: :articles
```

Or use `resources` shortcut instead:

```
resources :articles, only: %i[new create]
```